# Multiple errors-in-variables regression with collinearities

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, errors-in-variables, total-least-squares, deming-regression

I have a $[k \times N]$ matrix of predictors / independent variables and a $[k \times N]$ matrix of predictands / dependent variables.  I have uncertainty estimates for each predictor and each predictand.  I use orthogonal distance regression (ODR, with [scipys Python interface](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) to [ODRPACK](http://www.netlib.org/odrpack/)) to estimate my predictands one column at the time (regressing $[k \times N]$ as independent and $[1 \times N]$ as dependent), but my estimate of β (estimated parameter values) suffers from strong collinearities between the input vectors, i.e.

$y_8 = 1.3 - 0.046x₁ + 1.45x₂ - 1.49x₃ + 2.2x₃ - 1.4x₄ + \ldots + 1.1x₈ + \ldots$

...which in turn leads to my model being poorly generalised to independent testing data.  For physical reasons¹, I would expect that all but one factors of β are close to zero, and my initial guess for β is

$$
\beta_k = \cases{%
0 \quad k \neq i\\
1 \quad k = i}
$$

and I would expect the estimated $\beta$ to be close to it.

In practice, $k=12$ and $N$ is in the order of $10^3-10^5$.

How can I mitigate the problems caused by strong collinearities between the input vectors?  Can I penalise large deviations from expected coefficients or otherwise regularise input data?  Alternately, can I incorporate my errors-in-variables into methods better suited for collinear predictors, such as PLSR?  I am looking for a practical solution that is reasonably straightforward to implement using Python and available libraries.

---

¹ <sup>Physically,
I am comparing two N-channel radiometers with small, poorly known differences between corresponding channels, leading to small but nonzero expected differences in radiance.  My regression aims to get a better understanding of the differences.  Uncertainty estimates are essential to the project.</sup>